# How to list all classes in autocompletion inside annotations in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: autocomplete, intellij-idea

I have custom class **InternalTimerServiceController** in my application. I want to use it in another class inside android annotations. And it seems that autocompletion does not work correctly in this case.

I have this interface

```
public interface InternalTimerServiceControllerContract
{
    void doWork();
}
```

And this class

```
@EBean
public class InternalTimerServiceController implements InternalTimerServiceControllerContract
{
    @Override
    public void doWork()
    {
        // do work
    }
}
```

And this is my Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    // try uncomment line below and see if autocomplete works properly
    //@Bean(Internal) 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug, thanks for reporting. I've created a ticket for it: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98298